# Implementing CSP policy in node

Tags: node.js, header, content-security-policy

I am trying to define content-security-policy to get images from limited sources.

```
const csp = req.headers.set('Content-Security-Policy' : "default-src 'self'; img-src creativecommons.org staticflickr.com;")
```

This thing is not working for me. What will be the correct syntax for this??

Comment: Could you give us a bit of context? Like, give us the code around the statement you're showing us, and maybe tell us what framework you're using (if you are using a framework).

Comment: Also you need to be much more specific about what's "not working for you" - what exactly do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening instead.